# What Strange Place am I in?

Tags: riddle

As I sat there, a woman in black asked me if I had decided yet. I told her I hadn't, but she gave me a glass anyway. Later, she came again. This time I had decided. So, she went and got something from the man in white and brought it to me. When I was finished, I wasn't allowed to go until I gave her something extra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are in

> A restaurant

Explanation:
a woman in black asked me if I had decided yet. I told her I hadn't, but she gave me a glass anyway

> The waitress came to your table to see if you had decided on your meal and gave you the drink (in a glass) you had ordered already. Or a glass of water as some will give you without asking.

Later, she came again. This time I had decided

> You give her your order

So, she went and got something from the man in white and brought it to me.

> She got your order from the chef

When I was finished, I wasn't allowed to go until I gave her something extra.

> You had to pay before leaving.